# Modifiy GridFilters in ExtNet

Tags: extjs

I've add some filters to the columns of a `gridpanel` with this code :

```
<Features>
    <ext:GridFilters runat="server" ID="GridFilters1">
        <Filters>
            <ext:ListFilter DataIndex="Luogo"></ext:ListFilter>
            <ext:ListFilter DataIndex="Processo"></ext:ListFilter>
            <ext:ListFilter DataIndex="Scenario"></ext:ListFilter>
            <ext:ListFilter DataIndex="Si"></ext:ListFilter>
            <ext:ListFilter DataIndex="Sr"></ext:ListFilter>
            <ext:ListFilter DataIndex="Livello"></ext:ListFilter>
            <ext:ListFilter DataIndex="Approvato"></ext:ListFilter>
            <ext:ListFilter DataIndex="Respinto"></ext:ListFilter>
            <ext:ListFilter DataIndex="Task"></ext:ListFilter>
        </Filters>
    </ext:GridFilters>
</Features>
```

The result for each column is:

[image]

I'm wondering if is there a way to hide ( from html code ) all the fileds apart  "Filters" ( that is the only one that I need ).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML wise, you can disable the columns hide/show with the: EnableColumnHide="false" of the grid tag.

You can hide the Asc/Desc menu itens but you will have to use javascript to acheive it:

Use the following js function on grid render listener

```
    <Render Fn="hideMenuItems" />

    var hideMenuItems = function(grid){
         var ms = grid.view.hmenu.items;
         ms.get("asc").hide(true);
         ms.get("desc").hide(true);
     }
```

[Source](https://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?3548-CLOSED-Remove-sort-Asc-Desc-from-grid-header-context-menu)